# Jest - simulate is not a function on testing click on react link

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a react link and if it redirects to the correct destination on click. But, if I do a test like this:

```js
const link = dashboard.findByProps({to: '/classes'});
console.log(link);
link.simulate('click');
expect(testRenderer.root.instance.history.location.pathname).toEqual("/classes");
```

I get:

> TypeError: link.simulate is not a function

I have tried with `link.props.onClick()` as well, but that hasn't worked either. How can I test clicking the link with `Jest` in `react?`

Comment: `.findByProps` is specific to `react-test-renderer` while `simulate` is related to Enzyme. so what library do you use actually? also did you ensure `link` component(whatever it is) really should have `onClick` prop?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `react-test-renderer`, you should use [act](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendereract) method and dispatch DOM event like this:

```js
  act(() => {
    link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}));
  });
```

If you use `enzyme`, you should use [simulate](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html) method to trigger React `click`  event.

They are different. You'd better don't use them together.